# Click Event For A Button in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, click

I have a button that is displayed after a certain event is passed but it isn't created in the main window. How do I add a definition to that button so that it can handle a click event? ie:

```
        if (something == true)
        {
            Button Button = new Button();
            Button.Height = Y;
            Button.Width = X;
            Save.Margin = new Thickness(XX, YY, 0, 0);
            MyThing.Children.Add(button);
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Button.Click += delegate {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I'll add it as the answer ASAP.